# Solve $\frac{\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x} = \sin^2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm having troubles with some problems here is an example :
$$\begin{align}
{\frac{\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}} & = \sin^2x \\
\end{align}$$

Can someone explain to me step by step on how you got the answer.

Comment: Many of us can take it step by step. Can you show some effort?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is:

- $\tan(x) = \dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)},$
- $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$.

Try getting rid of the $\tan$'s first, then simplifying the fraction on the left a bit, and finally applying $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

The left hand side is $$\dfrac{\tan ^2 x}{\sec ^2 x} = \tan ^2 x \cdot \cos ^2 x$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Joe, please do not edit my answer(s) to include reasoning that I omitted. If you would like to see an answer that is more thorough, or that spoon feeds the OP, feel free to write your own. I have rolled back to original.

Answer (score 2):

The first time I ever saw the identity
$$
\tan(\alpha+\beta)=\text{a function of }\tan\alpha\text{ and }\tan\beta
$$
it was proved by changing it to
$$
\frac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\cos(\alpha+\beta)}
$$
and then applying the previously demostrated identities involving those.  The same thing works here:
$$
\frac{\tan^2 x}{1+\tan^2x} = \frac{\left(\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}\right)}{1+\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}}
$$
Multiplying both the top and bottom by $\cos^2 x$ gets rid of the fractions-within-fractions and gives you $\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x$ in the denominator.  You probably know that $\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x$ can be greatly simplified.

Comment: I saved this answer about 45 minutes ago, and it says here I answer two minutes ago.

Comment: ....and 30 seconds after I posted the comment above, it says I posted it "7 mins ago".

Comment: ....and _then_, a minute after _that_, it says my first comment above was "1 min ago".

Comment: I never edited my answer here after posting it.  I don't know what only the bottom half would appear.